# Paypal NVP API - Keep getting error 81002

Tags: php, paypal

I am new to PayPal API, and I'm having trouble calling SetExpressCheckout using CURL in PHP.
I have set everything correctly, as far as I'm concerned, but I kept getting an 81002 error "Method Specified is not Supported".

The code snippet is below. I got the CA Root certificates file from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

```
<?php

$paypal_data = array(
    'USER' => urlencode('andree_1272823561_biz_api1.gmail.com'),
    'PWD' => urlencode('1272823576'),
    'SIGNATURE' => urlencode('Am1t0wiu2tv7VwZ5ebdeY9zv1GF6Ad0PFz-qTGFFf7vbWU6ee4bxy8KL'),
    'VERSION' => urlencode('52.0'),
    'PAYMENTACTION' => urlencode('Sale'),
    'METHOD' => urlencode('SetExpressCheckout'),
    'AMT' => urlencode('52.00'),
    'RETURNURL' => urlencode('get_express_checkout_details.php'),
    'CANCELURL' => urlencode('index.php')
);

$url = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?' . http_build_query($paypal_data);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
parse_str($result, $result);
?>

<pre>Data sent: <?php print_r($paypal_data); ?></pre>
<pre>Result: <?php print_r($result); ?></pre>
```

When I run the code, the output is the following:

```
Data sent: Array
(
    [USER] => andree_1272823561_biz_api1.gmail.com
    [PWD] => 1272823576
    [SIGNATURE] => Am1t0wiu2tv7VwZ5ebdeY9zv1GF6Ad0PFz-qTGFFf7vbWU6ee4bxy8KL
    [VERSION] => 52.0
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [AMT] => 52.00
    [RETURNURL] => get_express_checkout_details.php
    [CANCELURL] => index.php
)

Result: Array
(
    [ACK] => Failure
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 81002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Unspecified Method
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Method Specified is not Supported
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Regards, Andree.

Comment: It runs fine with me, the only diff. is that I'm not using the certificate option, and added this two options curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

Comment: Hm .. weird. I've changed the CAINFO option with the two lines you suggested, and still I got the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is when you use urlencode + http_build_query. You will end up with double encoding and PayPal will reject some of the info.

Comment: I had this same issue with my own code just now. I discovered that I was 'double-encoding' the request and that was converting the `&` name-value pair delimiters as `%26`, hence the "Unspecified Method" error. [It's bad, and very confusing, that the error _also_ includes the 'long message' "Method Specified is not Supported" as that directly contradicts the 'short message'! I figured that I was being told that the `SetExpressCheckout` method wasn't supported!]

Comment: I had a similar problem because I'm using ';' as separator. Paypal only supports '&'.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and in the end discovered that it was a problem with getting the
parameters transmitted at all. I was using the following kind of code to pass the
parameters (as shown in various examples on the net for PayPal):

```
   http.set_form_data({"q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en"}, ';')
```

When I changed this to:

```
   http.form_data = {"q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en"}
```

it stopped giving me the unknown method error (and moved onto other errors :-)

The Ruby code below worked for me (I have removed the return URLs though).
The username etc are standard sandbox ones.

```
# http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html
# https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted

require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp')

request_object = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

request_object.form_data = {
'USER'=>'sdk-three_api1.sdk.com', # Sandbox value. See e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted
'PWD'=>'QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q',  # Sandbox value. See e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted
'SIGNATURE'=>'A-IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU',  # Sandbox value. See e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted
'METHOD'=>'SetExpressCheckout',
'VERSION'=>'88.0',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>'Sale',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'=>'23.00',  # Must have exactly two decimals for cents. See e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted above.
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'=>'USD',
'cancelUrl'=>'http://www.add your own URL here',
'returnUrl'=>'http://www.add your own URL here'
}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
# HACK: The following two lines turn off secure certificate checking!!
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request(request_object)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not using the PHP API, but I ran into the same 81002 error using the Callback API (java) and I got this when some of the parameters were either missing or badly formated.

I don't know if you solved the issue, but my advice would be checking which of the parameters are **requred** for the SetExpressCheckout ([API Reference](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1372)). And than if you have set those, check if the ***limitations*** part of the description of the parameter is satisfied.

Sadly but they sometimes throw inappropriate errors (or errors that the developer can't quite understand). On the other side I usually get most of my responses answered on their forum. If in "trouble" you can also write a private message to the paypal team member on shift (or to a person that has already solved your problem).

Hope that helped!
Despot

Comment: Uggh; the API reference documentation is not very good. For example, for the `SetExpressCheckout` operation, apparently the parameter `AMT` has been "deprecated" but it's somehow also "required"! It's seemingly not _really_ required as I was able to make a successful request for that operation without including that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

***There is major issue with all.  simply pass all param on body key***

example

```
wp_remote_post("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp",
                array(
                    'timeout'   => 60,
                    'sslverify' => FALSE,
                    'httpversion' => '1.1',
                    'body' => "METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=72.0&PWD="" &USER=''&SIGNATURE=''&RETURNURL=''&CANCELURL=''&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment"
)
```